# unable to get row and column count (using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel )

Tags: c#, excel

I am able to open and read the excel file properly, however the output does not stop. It keeps going when there are empty cells. How can I make the program stop once it reaches the cell with no data?

I have read other posts and have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264321/interop-excel-usedrange-rows-count-incorrect#_=_) post as well since the solution is a little similar. What is wrong with the code?

Thank you for the help

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program
    {
        private static int colCount;
        private static int rowCount;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\File.xlsx");
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;


            int rowCount = xlWorksheet.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlWorksheet.Columns.Count;

            for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
                {
                    //new line
                    if (j == 1)
                    {
                        Console.Write("\r\n"); 

                    }

                    //write the value to the console
                    if (xlWorksheet.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
                    {
                        Console.Write(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString() + "\t");
                    }
                }
            }

            //cleanup
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            //rule of thumb for releasing com objects:
            //  never use two dots, all COM objects must be referenced and released individually
            //  ex: [somthing].[something].[something] is bad

            //release com objects to fully kill excel process from running in the background
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

            //close and release
            xlWorkbook.Close();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);

            //quit and release
            xlApp.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
        }
    } }
```

Comment: xlRange.Rows.Count instead of xlWorksheet.Rows.Count

Comment: @Slai, tried that. Still does the same thing.

Comment: there are many ways to [find the last used cell](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/918/methods-for-finding-the-last-used-row-or-column-in-a-worksheet), but it also depends on what you do after. If you just want the data in a tab separated string, you can just `xlWorksheet.Cells.Copy` and get the text from the clipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked. I got it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353073/c-sharp-excel-correct-way-to-get-rows-and-columns-count) s.o post. If someone could explain the `System.Reflection.Missing.Value`, it would be very helpful.

```
// Find the last real row
lastUsedRow = worksheet.Cells.Find("*",System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 
                               System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 
                               Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, 
                               false,System.Reflection.Missing.Value,System.Reflection.Missing.Value).Row;

// Find the last real column
lastUsedColumn = worksheet.Cells.Find("*", System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 
                               System.Reflection.Missing.Value,System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 
                               Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns,Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, 
                               false,System.Reflection.Missing.Value,System.Reflection.Missing.Value).Column;
```