# C#/Excel: Recover Number Error in Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have a prob lem with excel and c#. When I set in the cell A1 a number like 123456789.

In all column A when the format is Number, next code is working without problems:

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook(stream);
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
var count = worksheet.Cells.Count; // count is 1
```

If I have column A design in format Text, converts that cell as '123456789 and then the code is wrong and returns me count=126 and when I query the cells all cells from 2 to 126 are empty or null and A1 as '1234567890

Why is happening that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out something like

```
Excel.Range range;
range = worksheet.UsedRange;
var count = range.Count;
```

It's a problem othersalready got.

Source : [Interop Excel UsedRange Rows Count incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264321/interop-excel-usedrange-rows-count-incorrect)